# mysql delete if exists

Tags: mysql, sql

how can I delete if the row exists like this select statement. I tried replacing select with delete but it didn't work. 
I a need statement that deletes and return 1 if the row exists. Or it returns 0 if the row is not found in the table.

```
SELECT IF ( EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `cancellation` WHERE `ID`=2), 1, 0)
```

Comment: In what language are you using this? The correct course would be to simply execute a `DELETE FROM cancellation WHERE ID=2` and then check the number of affected rows to see if a deletion actually occurred.

Comment: what if the affected rows is zero because the statement failed.

Comment: That should throw an error/exception rather than returning a count.

Answer (score 3):

You should execute two statements. First, your delete:

```
DELETE FROM `cancellation` WHERE `ID` = 2
```

To get a count, follow your DELETE immediately with this:

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT()
```

Anything greater than 0 will be a successful delete.

---

**Update: Three-value logic in PHP**

If you're using PHP and want to use some trickery, use a null value to indicate failure of the DELETE process.  PHP's mysqli_query will return false if the delete operation failed, so we can use that to force a NULL return value.

```
<?php
   function zapper ($row_id) {
      if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM `cancellation` WHERE `ID` = " . $row_id) === TRUE) {
         if (mysqli_affected_rows($connection) > 0) {
            // delete successful - some rows were deleted
            return TRUE;
         } else {
            // delete successful - no rows were deleted
            return FALSE;
         }
      } else {
         // delete unsuccessful
         return NULL;
      }
   }
?>
```

Comment: @Michael: Yeah, caught that after I hit the post button.

Comment: The problem with this is that if the row doesn't exist it will return false because row_count() is 0. I want to return true if the row is deleted or the row doesn't exist

Comment: @nullException: You're confusing me. Under what condition do you expect a false return?

Comment: only if the rows is in the table but cannot be deleted for any reason (exception, error or restrictions). The flow should look like this 
func foo(row_id){
  if (row_id is in the table) {
     if (delete(row_id)==success) {
         return true;
     }
  }else{
     return false;
  }
}

Comment: Is this being called from PHP? If so, which extension?

Comment: @nullException Via PHP, the workflow is the same. You have to do the deletion either way, so there's no need to first test if the row exists. Pseudocode:  `function foo(row_id){ DELETE FROM table WHERE id=row_id; if (mysql_affected_rows() >= 1) return true; else return false; }`

Comment: @nullException The function returns what _you code it to return_ so invert your logic.

Comment: your function return false if the row_id is not in the table.

Comment: @nullException: It sounds like you need three results out of a boolean function. It can't be done unless you want to mess around with a null value in PHP. I updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score -2):

Delete query always returns
0 --> when record is not deleted
1 --> at successfull delete
like:
String sql="delete from marks where id=101;
flag=stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

Comment: The reason for down votes is that the boolean value of 1, indicating success, is returned when the conditions are such that the record being referenced does not exist in the table. MySQL thinks, since the record does not exist it must mean it successfully deleted the record.  What is being explained is how one gets to distinguish a successful delete status only when the record existed in the first place, as opposed to a successful delete status because the record does not exist in the table.